# HTML element is represented in JavaScript as a global variable , How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Does JavaScript represent each HTML element as a global variable which name is the id of the element ?

Let's say I have a hidden input element like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="10" id="myInput" />
```

so I can access it in JavaScript :

```
console.log(myInput.value);
```

I tried it in chrome and firefox, and it worked for me.

My question is :

- Is this issue new in JavaScript ?
- Is it the best practice to get an element by id ?
- Why they implement this functionality although using global variables is not the best practice?

Answer (score 4):

That is called as `named access`. Every element which has `an` id will be referenced in global scope. That is the `window object`. Even though it is not a good practice to use it, it is standardised with `HTML5`.

A simple conflicting case for its usage is,

If you declare a variable in global scope like `hide`, and also you are having an `element` in your `document` with `id` `hide`. Then that element reference will be overridden by our `global variable`. At that time, if you use it(`element` reference) in any event handler or somewhere, it will results in error.